# Securely execute shell script via website

Tags: php, apache, bash, shell, scripting

I'm trying to run a shell script using php exec.

The thing is - this isn't very secure as I am posting to it via a html text box i.e.

```
<?php
$output = shell_exec ('whois '.$_POST['domain']);
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

The thing is... if a user entered `| rm -rf *`

It would delete everything in the folder.

Is there a secure way of executing shell scripts and preventing this from happening?

Thanks

Comment: I think you have to take the input from user and parse it , if it is acceptable then run it else prompt user that this command you can't run it here.

Comment: You need to validate the post data before sending it to the shell - I think this is a recipe for pain on a public server - can you not force them to select from a list of options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is always a function to escape user data being passed to another system.  In the case of shell commands, there is [escapeshellarg](http://php.net/escapeshellarg).  No matter what other kind of validation you do on user input, it is always a good idea to escape arguments just before you pass them to the shell function.

For example:

```
$domain_arg = escapeshellarg( $_POST['domain'] );
$output = shell_exec( 'whois ' . $domain_arg );
```

Answer (score 0):

you want to do a whois. so you need to validate if it containes only the parts you want. in your case a domain and nothing else.

```
if (preg_match('/^(?:[-A-Za-z0-9]+\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,6}$/', $_POST['domain']))
{
    $output = shell_exec('whois ' . $_POST['domain']);
    echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
}
else
{
    echo "stop trying to make my server annoyed";
}
```